# Android, Facebook Login Button Causes Crash (SDK 4.0.0)

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

In my activity `.xml` file, I include the Facebook Login Button (from [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3) documentation)

```
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Immediately I get a warning saying that

```
The following classes could not be found:
    - com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
```

The documentation says to

> Add the button to your layout XML file with the full class name,
>   com.facebook.widget.LoginButton

But changing that top line does nothing. The app crashes immediately, without opening, and nothing is recorded in the log cat (testing on external device).

Removing the button, or changing it to

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

stops the crash, but this is my first time working with the Facebook SDK and don't know if the regular button will work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());` before inflating the view..

- If this xml is used in activity, write above line before `setContentView()`

- If this xml is used in fragment, write this line before `inflater.inflate...`

And, just ignore the warning shown in layout preview window

Comment: I am having a new issue with the Facebook Login. I've posted it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334263/android-facebook-login-only-good-for-one-login-then-receives-error), if you have any thoughts on it? Thanks.

Comment: Nice answer, works like butter, thanks @Ankit Bansal