# Android, Facebook Login only good for ONE login, then receives error?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using the new Facebook SDK (4.0.0). I am implementing a FB login, and it works fine for ONE login, but if you log out and then try to log in again, you get the following error:

[image: Facebook Login Error]

This is all without closing the app, or modifying code or anything. Just log in, then out, then attempt to log in again.

The hash (blacked out) isn't even the same hash that my computer provides. There are similar threads talking about this problem, but no easy solutions, other than the remedy discussed below.

The only way I've found to remedy this problem is to delete the app from my Facebook Developers page, and create the app all over again, to get a new App ID. This is my first time using Facebook login, and so I am testing a couple things I'd like to happen when the user logs in. Is there any method to avoid this, so that I can log IN and OUT as many times as required?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929153/invalid-hash-key-in-facebook-app-in-android/25035885#25035885

Comment: The second method in the answer did the trick. Thanks.